# How to calculate the Bayesian posterior analytically and by simulation?

Tags: bayesian, posterior

I am working with this model:

Prior: $P(\lambda)$~ N(0, 1), only the positive part

likelihood:  $P(x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda x}$  or $P(\vec{x}|\lambda)=\prod(1-e^{-\lambda x})$

Posterior: $P(\lambda|\vec{x})$

What is $P(\lambda|\vec{x})$ ?

I have something looks like this:

[image: Bayesian]

My understanding is that $P(x)$ is always a density function.
In here, my model is NOT a density, it is a exponential cdf.  So, I am a bit confused.  Is my model wrong, is this possible?  Thanks!

Comment: I always thought it is the pdf, but my colleague told me his model is $1-e^{\lambda x}$, and thus the likelihood.  I think it is impossible.  Could you confirm?

Comment: @Xi'an: I disagree. It makes perfect sense to use the CDF in the likelihood - just try to find the likelihood to the following question: 
20 identical components were installed in an electrical substation 1000 days ago. You are asked to estimate the distribution of the time to failure of such components based on the observations of failure times in this substation. The observed values are in increasing order
[in days]:
64, 396, 662, 714, 725, 848, 897, 985.
12 components are still working after 1000 days.
Assume that time to failure has the Exponential distribution.

Comment: @Summit: in your censored example, the observed random variable is mixed, with pdf $$\lambda\exp\{-x\lambda\}\mathbb{I}(x<1000) + \exp(-\lambda 1000)\mathbb{I}(x=1000)$$ so even in this case one uses the pdf of the observed random variable.

Comment: @Xi'an: You are right. I was a bit sloppy in my expression. The point is: $\exp(-\lambda1000)$ is actually 1-CDF(of Exponential distribution). Imagine that  the likelihood in my example is only defined with respect to the second term. However, in your answer you transformed it to the type appearing in the first term. (does this make sense to you?)

Comment: @Summit: if you only observe censored observations, since they are censored at $x_i$ with probability $\exp(-\lambda x_i)$, this is their _pmf_ and not _cdf_, so there is no inconsistency. From there, in practice, the posterior will be $$\exp\left\{-\lambda\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - \lambda^2/2\right\}$$ and hence a truncated normal.

Comment: @Xi'an: I fully agree with you. I was just trying to say that I strongly believe: The likelihood posted in the question, i.e. $\prod(1-\exp(-\lambda x))$ should not be transformed to $\prod(\lambda\exp(-\lambda x))$ as you did it in your answer. However, before agreeing, I guess that we need to clarify what the observed data actually are ...

Comment: @Summit: yes indeed, the originator of the data should clarify this point. Note that a difficulty with using the version $$\prod_{i=1} [1-\exp(-\lambda x_i)]$$ is that the MLE is $\hat\lambda=+\infty$, i.e., it does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A model distribution and a prior distribution are defined by either their pdf or their cdf. So your dataset is an exponential sample with parameter $\lambda$, which means that
$$
F_\lambda(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}\ \text{ and }\ f_\lambda(x)=\lambda e^{-x\lambda}
$$
are the cdf and pdf for this model. Therefore the likelihood function is defined as
$$
L(\lambda|x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_\lambda(x_i) = \lambda^n \exp\left\{-\lambda\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right\}\,.
$$
If your prior on $\lambda$ is a truncated normal $\text{N}(0,1)$, then its pdf is given by
$$
\pi(\lambda) = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}\ \exp\{-\lambda^2/2\}\mathbb{I}_{\lambda>0}\,.
$$
(The cdf is irrelevant for the computation of the posterior.)

Now the posterior distribution is defined via Bayes' formula by
$$
\pi(\lambda|x_1,\ldots,x_n) \propto \pi(\lambda) L\lambda|x_1,\ldots,x_n)\,.
$$
Hence,
\begin{align*}
\pi(\lambda|x_1,\ldots,x_n) &\propto \lambda^n \exp\{-\lambda^2/2\} \exp\left\{-\lambda\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right\}\mathbb{I}_{\lambda>0}\\
&\propto \lambda^n \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\lambda+\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2\right\}\mathbb{I}_{\lambda>0}
\end{align*}
which is the density of a non-standard distribution.

Comment: (+1) I wonder why he would use this prior when a conjugate one is available. He can even use a mixture of gamma's as his prior, which is quite flexible.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  Is it common practice take log likelihood?  I can never accurately decide.  Your work looks great without it.

Comment: I have tried MLE, looks like it's just $\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n {x_i}$, so my posterior should be something close.

Comment: The last sentence "which is the density of a non-standard distribution."  My colleague wants me to give the distribution of $\lambda$, he wants the form $1-e^{-\lambda x}$, is that possible?  I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Could you explain how you got last step, $\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\lambda^2+\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2\right\}$?  If I expand the squared term, I'd get $\lambda^4$.

Comment: You probably meant $\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\lambda+\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2\right\}$, that's what I got from you work.

Comment: @zen Yes, I should be using gamma as a prior, thanks!

Comment: Note that you changed the meaning of the observations in your answer: 
- in the question: We observed events DATA<=x;
- in your answer: DATA=x.
Using the PDF or the CDF in the likelihood is a fundamentally different problem. Especially in combination with the exponential distribution, the use of the CDF makes perfect sense.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $$\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\lambda+\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2\right\}$$ (cut&paste typo...)

Comment: @Summit I don't understand, could you elaborate?  Why would cdf make perfect sense?

Comment: Summit wonders if your data is made from exponential $x_i\sim\mathcal{E}(\lambda)$ observations or from censored exponential durations $x_i$, ie you only know that the exponential durations are at most $x_i$, which happens with probability $1-e^{-\lambda x_i}$.

Comment: @Xi'an I discussed with my colleague today.  The model is $y = 1- e^{-\lambda{x}}+\epsilon$ where, $\epsilon \sim N(0, 1)$.  So, the likelihood model the product of $y_i \sim N(1-e^{\lambda{x_i}}, 1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $X_1,\dots,X_n$, given $\Lambda=\lambda$, are conditionally independent and identically distributed, such that $X_1\sim\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$, and you believe *a priori* that $\Lambda\sim\mathrm{Ga}(\alpha_0,\beta_0)$, in which $\alpha_0,\beta_0>0$ are specified real numbers.

After you get a sample $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, the likelihood is the sampling density seem as a function of $\lambda$.
$$
  L_x(\lambda) = f_{X_1,\dots,X_n\mid\Lambda}(x_1,\dots,x_n\mid\lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_{X_i\mid\Lambda}(x_i\mid\lambda) = \lambda^n e^{-\lambda\sum_{i=1}^n x_i} \,I_{(0,\infty)}(\lambda)\, .
$$

Bayes' Theorem gives
$$
  f_{\Lambda\mid X_1,\dots,X_n}(\lambda\mid x_1,\dots,x_n) \propto L_x(\lambda)\,f_\Lambda(\lambda) \propto \lambda^{\alpha_0+n-1} e^{-(\beta_0+\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)\lambda}\,I_{(0,\infty)}(\lambda) \, ,
$$
yielding that *a posteriori*
$$
  \Lambda\mid X_1=x_1,\dots,X_n=x_n\sim\mathrm{Ga}\!\left(\alpha_0+n,\beta_0+\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) \, .
$$
The Bayes estimate with quadratic loss is
$$
  \mathrm{E}\left[\Lambda\mid X_1=x_1,\dots,X_n=x_n\right] = \frac{\alpha_0+n}{\beta_0+\sum_{i=1}^n x_i} \, .
$$
A credible interval can be obtained by Monte Carlo.

```
a0 <- 6
b0 <- 20

n <- 45
x <- rexp(n, rate = 5)

N <- 10^6

level <- 0.95

post <- rgamma(N, shape = a0 + n, rate = b0 + sum(x))

cat("Bayes estimate:", (a0+n)/(b0+sum(x)), "\n")
cat(sprintf("%.2f", level*100), "% Credible Interval: [ ", 
    quantile(post,(1-level)/2), " ; ", 
    quantile(post,(1+level)/2), " ]\n", sep = "")
```

Comment: Your likelihood is an exponential density.  I have $1-e^{-\lambda x}$, the exponential cdf, as my likelihood model.  How do you work with cdf?

Comment: Then I'm afraid your model makes no sense. For each fixed $\lambda$, the likelihood must be a density/pmf for the $x_i$'s. Try to check this in your case.

Comment: I thought so too.  But can't Bayesian inference be applied to any model?  What if your model is a regression?  That's not a density.  I was following this.  http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/bayesian-analysis-for-a-logistic-regression-model.html

Comment: You have to apply the correct version of Bayes' formula: $$\pi(\lambda|x) \propto \pi(\lambda) p(x|\lambda)$$ operates on densities (pdfs), not cdfs. And the likelihood of a sample is the product of the individual densities, not of the individual cdfs.

Comment: @user13985: you're rushing and trying to do inference without understanding the concepts. This book is an excellent option: http://tinyurl.com/kqsnycq.

Comment: @Xi'an & Zen: My colleague tells me his model is $1-e^{-\lambda x}$, I have argued that it is impossible, he must give me a pdf.

Comment: Ask him to consider $\lambda=1$ and sum over $x$ (just one observation will be enough).

Comment: @Xi'an & Zen: I bought that book last year.  I have also been to one of your(Xi'an) talk.

Comment: Thanks for buying the book, you should re-check Chapter 1 for the proper definitions of the prior and likelihood.